# Open embedded objects in word on OS X

Tags: macos, ms-office

I need to open zip files embedded in a word doc on Mac OS X. However that functionality is not available upon clicking or through any of the menu options on Word for Mac. So I tried to copy paste the embeddings in a different file and saved that file as something.zip instead of something.docx. This when opened with Archive utility led me to the folder structure and ultimately the folder "embeddings" that contained the actual embedding as someOleObject.bin

If I know the content of the zip files, i.e. if they contain *.doc or *.pdf I can simply change someOleObject.bin to someOleObject.pdf and recover it [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3054435?tstart=0) is the Apple community post most accurately describing this solution, incase someone needs it for reference.

However I don't know the content of the zip files, so once I reach the embeddings and try to rename the someOleObject.bin to someOleObject.zip and open using Archive, it spawns more someOleObject2.bin type of files.

I'd appreciate any solutions to work around the above issue.